# LyX in Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon does not display the correct characters in maths mode. How can I fix this?

Tags: symbols, lyx, linux

I recently installed the latest Mint OS and installed TexLive-full, then LyX 
(via terminal). Unfortunately some symbols aren't shown up correctly within LyX itself. For example typing `\alpha`, `\beta`, `\gamma`, `\delta`, `\epsilon` in math mode displays "a", "b", "g", "d". Mysteriously epsilon displays correctly. The PDF output is as expected. Nearly all maths symbols are affected. I have tried reinstalling everything from scratch but it doesn't make a difference. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running LyX from the command line instead of via a menu or similar. Might just be some fonts that it needs that it for some reason did not install when you installed LyX it self. Often these warnings are written to standard error/out and this hidden when you don't start the programme from a command line

Comment: @daleif Yes I ran it from the command line at first so that doesn't change anything but I do think you're right about missing fonts. Another thing that isn't showing in math mode is a minus sign which instead displays "lyxminus". Do you know how to go about adding fonts for LyX?

Comment: It is not that is changes anything, it any warnings appear?

Comment: At least you can get information about what lyx depends on via `apt list lyx`, I don't know if mint repackages lyx (I don't think so). Do you happen to know exactly which texlive the latest Mint is using? (I never use the LaTeX from Linux dists)

Comment: @daleif Sorry, no, no warning appeared. Mint installs texlive 2017.20180305-1 in amd64 from the ubuntu bionic repository and lyx 2.3.2-1.

Comment: Then I suggest you ask on the lyx forum/mailinglist, https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Comment: Off topic for LyX issues you can review the internal TeX status report where it will undoubtedly report many fonts not installed (mine has many I don't use like Garamond) Those such as amsmath etc are generally available and shown status: yes equally in TeX you can use tlmg --gui to review if fontutils needs a reload and update font mappings

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same exact problem; in order to fix it, I simply installed LyX-fonts from the Synaptic Package Manager.

Open the menu > search > Synaptic Package Manager. Then, once in the package manager, click on the magnifying glass "search for packages" icon, and type "lyx". You should receive many LyX related packages, and one of them is called "fonts-lyx." Install this package, then proceed to open LyX and reconfigure. From here, all the fonts should revert back to normal working order.

Comment: Please, ellaborate more your answer giving links and pieces of code :D

Comment: Hi! There was no terminal usage involved. Open the menu > search > Synaptic Package Manager. Then, once in the package manager, click on the magnifying glass "search for packages" icon, and type "lyx".  You should receive many LyX related packages, and one of them is called "fonts-lyx." Install this package, then proceed to open LyX and reconfigure. From here, all the fonts should revert back to normal working order. I hope this helps!

Comment: Alright! I completed your answer with the given information in your comment. Have a nice day!

Comment: @PilarOrellana Nice first answer! Welcome to tex.se! I'm sorry you got downvoted. I think your original answer was OK except that you did not include the name of the package (package names are helpful if someone wants to use apt-get instead of Synaptic). In any case, Sebastian's edits provided a nice clarification. Here is the LyX bug report (that gives the same solution as yours): https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10637. Thanks for your time to register and add your helpful answer. +1 for your answer and +1 to Sebastian's edits. I hope the downvote doesn't discourage you from future answers.

Comment: +1 too, but shorter:  `sudo apt-get install fonts-lyx; lyx`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

The problem now seems to be fixed. I removed LyX from the system entirely and used synaptic package manager to install LyX rather than apt (command line tool). This may have installed a more recent version, as it is the most up to date release available according to https://repology.org/project/lyx/version which is the full list of LyX versions for Linux.